# C - How to replace a \n with a null in a text file

Tags: c, function, methods

I'm brand new to C and struggling. Basically, what I need to do is, go through an array, find the `\n`, and replace it with null. I'm sort of struggling with how I'd go about this. I sort of get it.

In pseudo, based on other minimal coding experience, I want to iterate over an array (for loop), if the string is = `"\n"` then replace it with null, and if the string is already null, it means we're at the end, so you have to break.

```
void replaceNwO (char* txtPtr) {
   char *txtPtr = strstr(filepath,"\n");
   for (i = 0; i < TEXT_LEN; i++)  {
      if(txtPtr != null) {
         strncpy(txtPtr,"\0",1);
         char* = strstr(filepath,"\n");
       }
       else {
          i++;
       }
   }
```

Can somebody help me see what I'm doing wrong? Pointers are confusing me. My logic is to iterate over a given file path name (a text file in my dir), iterate until we are at the text length capacity, and then replace those new line chars with a null line char. Otherwise, keep iterating.

I'm really trying...but more experienced eyes may help

Comment: you don't want to use string operations, you're concerned with single characters (`'\n'` is a single character, as is `'\0'`). Loop through all the characters in your string, and when you find `'\n'`, replace it with `'\0'` using a simple assignment (eg, `char myChar = '\0';`)

Comment: `strncpy(txtPtr,"\0",1);` same as doing `strncpy(txtPtr,"",1);` which I think is _nothing_.

Comment: ocikreowicmo, Add clarity: do you ant to iterate through an _array_ or a _file_?  What is the soruce of the data?

Comment: I'm sort of confused what that looks like. Am I looping through correctly? The pointer input is confusing me as well at the top with char* pointing to txtPtr. Not asking to do it straight up, but can you potentially add some pseudo structure? IDK how off I am

Comment: In the end, I have a text file in the same directory with this. I want to be able to apply these changes to that file when its called. If that makes any sense, I'm hugely confused also. But, this does need to apply to a given text file in the dir

Comment: What is `filePath`?

Comment: @ocikreowicmo Tip: Rather than replace `'\n'` with `'\0'`, replace with something printable like `'*'`.  Then after getting all to work, change to `'\0'`.  It will be easier to debug with `'*'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the string until you get to a null character. At each step, check if the current character is newline, in which case you replace it with the null character.

To replace a character, just assign through the pointer.

```
void replaceNwO (char* txtPtr) {
    for (; *textPtr != '\0'; textPtr++) {
        if (*textPtr == '\n') {
            *textPtr = '\0'; // replace newline with null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to C but receive one error at least. warning implicit delcaration of built-in function 'strchr' enabled by default.

Comment: You need to include `<string.h>`, just like you need for `strstr()`.

Comment: Oh...I can't. I only have stdlib.h, stdio.h, and ctype.h. Is there any other way?

Comment: Then how were you able to use `strstr()`?

Comment: @ocikreowicmo If you have restrictions, post them in the question, rather than piecemeal comments else we have a moving target.

Comment: I forgot to edit the code. Apologies. I was working with string.h to just see if I could get it, but in the end and I can't use it. Posted the wrong version...is there any way you can help me without it? If not it's fine, but I've been at this for hours and have multiple version

Comment: Those are the only restrictions. Apologies

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to iterate character by character.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry for the confusion. Can you explain what the ; means in the for loop? ie for( ; ...)

Comment: Rather `if (*textPtr == '\n') {
            *textPtr = '\0'; break;
        }`  as  first `\n` terminates the string

Comment: Wait, what? Can you elaborate? Do I need to make a change?

Comment: @P__J__ I understood they want to replace *all* the newlines, not just the first one.

Comment: Yes. All not just the first. How would it be re-written? Just adding the break?

Comment: @ocikreowicmo `;` is the separator between the initialization, condition, and repetition sections of the `for()` header. In this case the initialization is empty.

Comment: @ocikreowicmo It shouldn't be rewritten, this does what you want.

Comment: OK - as long as it replaces all of the \n and not just the first one, it's fine. Was confused. I thought you need to add a break after and then textPtr++ to continue to iterate.

Comment: @string with many terminations will not be very usefull

Answer (score 1):

I would make this function a bit more universal:

1. It is good to return the pointer to the string. It allows you to use it directly in the function calls or assignments
2. Function can be much more univeral  not only for this replacement in your program.
3. Add some simple parameter chack (at leat NULL pointer will not be dereferenced.

```
char *replace(char *haystack, char needle, char replace, int breakAfterFirst)
{
    char *wrk = haystack;
    if(haystack)
    {
        while(*wrk)
        {
            if(*wrk == needle) 
            {
                *wrk == replace;
                if(breakAfterFirst) break;
            }
            wrk++;
        }
    }
    return haystack;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void replaceNwO (char* txtPtr) {
   char *txtPtr = strstr(filepath,"\n");
   while(*txtPtr != '\0')
   {
     if(*txtPtr == '\n')
     {
       *txtPtr = '\0';
       break;
     }
     else
     {
       txtPtr++;
     }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. One restriction is I only have stdlib.h and stdio.h and ctype.h. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Should `strstr(filepath,"\n");` fail to find a `'\n'`, `*txtPtr != '\0'` is UB as `txtPtr == NULL`. As I see it, `char *txtPtr = strstr(filepath,"\n");` can be eliminated.